# I need help with sql and data relation tables

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010

i building a mini forum site.. and i constructed a few tables.

1) Users
2) Threads
3) Comments
4) Topics

i build a function that would insert a comment each time a user would submit a comment:

```
         string saveComment = "INSERT INTO Comments(";
     saveComment += " UsersID, ThreadsID, Date, Comments, CommentResponse";


     saveComment += "Values('" + "','";// no idea what to insert in the UsersID
     saveComment += "" + "','";// no idea what to insert in the ThreadsID

     saveComment += DateTime.Now + "','";
     saveComment += CommenttxtBox.Text + "','";
     saveComment += commentResponseString + "')";
```

As you can see the fields have UsersID and ThreadID, both connected by a foreign key to the comments table. 
Now, each time the user submits a comment, i guess i need to insert also to the UsersID field (which is an int in the comments table, and that field increases incrementally by 1 in the Users table). How can i insert a comment, and notify the other table not to increase the UserID by 1. in fact i want it the UserID to stay the same for each user submitting a comment..

How do i do that? i need to insert to a few fields in one table (comments) but keep the other tables informed that it is actually the same user who submitted the comment .

Note: i dont know any vb, only c#, and i use visual studio 2010. asp.net

Comment: struggling to understand the question here, why would an insert into the Comments table have any effect on other tables?

Comment: Because, they are connected by links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a very standard normalised structure.  Your `Users` table will be responsible for controlling the `UserID` values that are generated.

You have two situations to cope with when inserting new comments:

1. The User exists and is logged in.
2. The User does not exist and is anonymous.

In the first situation, when you are inserting the comments you will not need to bother looking at the `Users` table.  This assumes you have the `UserID` already loaded (as the user is logged in).

In the second situation, you will first need to a new row to the `Users` table and return the `UserID` that the table generates (assuming you are using an identity column).  You can then pass this value to the `Comments` table.

The following script is an example of addressing the second situation:

```
DECLARE @userId int

INSERT INTO Users (Username, FirstName)
VALUES ('adamh', 'Adam')

SET @userId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO Comments(UserId, ThreadId, Comment)
VALUES (@userId, 1, 'My comment')
```

If you want to continue with your current coding style, simply concatenate the values into the relevant parts of the string.

However, with such as neatly defined structure as the one you have, I'd advise using something like Entity Framework 4.0, or LINQ to SQL, which cuts a lot of plumbing out once you have defined your structures.

Comment: i think i need to learn more sql, cause i dont understand what all those values mean.. Set , Declare... do you think there is a way to convert SQL to C#. i know it is done, when you use put a table attribute [table] above a class, and then use the class.. but i forgot how it is done

Answer (score 1):

BTW, the way you are inserting is a security issue, you could get SQL injection ...

Use the system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameters to passe values.

Comment: is there a way to convert those tables into objects? so that i will be able to program with c#

Comment: LINQtoSQL would be a solution ... but personnaly, I dont like it. If you are looking for optimized data manipulation, you will need to build your own objects.

Comment: why dont you like it? whats the disadvantage of it. if i use SQL commands, it is a lot of statements to write, and it also means i need to start learning sql. i dont know sql language!!

Comment: SQL is pretty easy. And LINQ syntax is not so easy. LINQ will generate lots of sql querys that could be simplified in a single query ... Depends on the complexity of your project.

Comment: i read in a book about ADO.NET and linq to sql. LINQ approach is easier to me, cause i am used to C#, and i am new to SQL syntax.. all it takes is to put a using statement, create an object/or get it back, modify it, and return it into the table..easy!!